# CRUD implementation of 50 pages - ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, crud, cascade

**I have to develop an application with 50 CRUD pages (SaaS)**. Clients will select/add pages based on there requirements (like facility, dept etc)
And these 50 pages may change from client to client some can only have 10 and other can have 15 etc.
Like for Some client Facility may exists and for some it may not.

I am using **ASP.NET CORE 3.0 with MVC Framework**

**What is the best way to do it?**

Also there are many cascaded drop-downs to handle as well.

For Location, Add page there is just 1 dropdown - Company
For Sub Location, 2 dropdown - Company and Location
and so on..

Page examples

1. Company
2. Location
3. Sub Location
4. Facility
5. Sub Facility
6. Department
7. Sub Dept
8. Room
   Etc

Comment: Is this being delivered as SaaS? You'd likely need some settings which control what pages are available to each client. It's unclear whether that's controlled by the system administrator, or by the client themselves, or if the software is downloaded by the client then it would need to be a build step or something. You haven't given enough detail for anyone to help you on that specific issue, but equally you're also asking about multiple distinct features at once in a single post, which is generally considered off-topic here.

Comment: Yes it gonna be delivered as SaaS. Since different client have different organisation layout they may need some pages and can leave others. Building webapp based on each client requirement is a lot of workload, hence I want to give client an option to choose or add the pages as they wish. I have update question as well. I hope this give more insight

Comment: With SaaS you don't build a separate version for each client, that's the whole point of that delivery method. You have a base product and then either provision a separate instance for each client automatically, or they just create an organisational account, and then add users under it, all within one big cloud instance of the app. Depends on the clients' needs. Then you need a control panel for each client where their admin can switch features on and off, and then code in your app itself which only loads a feature if the requesting client has enabled it

Comment: Sounds like maybe you haven't given this a lot of thought and/or haven't got much experience of these kinds of applications. There is a lot to think about and maybe you should speak to an expert consultant in-depth, or ask for more help within your own organisation if it has the expertise. P.S. I can't really help you with the cascading dropdown part of your question - I don't understand what you think the problem is. Cascading dropdowns aren't particularly difficult to implement. You'd have to be more specific about what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still relevant but we've recently published an open-source library [EasyData](https://github.com/KorzhCom/EasyData) that I believe can help you with this task (provided that you use Entity Framework Core for database operations).

With EasyData you can configure which entities should be open for each user. Dropdowns are also supported.

Comment: It looked like a nice option, I will try it